# Ruby - Send message to multiple IP addresses

Tags: ruby, sockets, chat

How would I go about sending one message to multiple receivers?

This is essentially what I would like to do:

```
    require 'socket'
ip = ['IP 1', 'IP 2']
port = 18000
loop {
    message = gets.chomp()
    conn = TCPSocket.open(ip, port)
    conn.write(message)
    conn.close_write
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to iterate over the ips array:

```
ips = ['IP 1', 'IP 2']
port = 18000

loop do 
  message = gets.chomp()

  ips.each do |ip|
    conn = TCPSocket.open(ip, port)
    conn.write(message)
    conn.close_write
  end
end
```